# Giving an error must declare a variable, but I already declared the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a weird error message must declare a variable @NextVal. But I already declare still it is giving me an error.

```
DECLARE @NextVal BIGINT
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@NextVal BIGINT OUTPUT', @NextVal OUTPUT
```

Does anyone has any idea???

Comment: Where you declare it? You have shown only the code where you use the variable.

Comment: Perhaps instead of "fixing" the variable issue we should help you eliminate the need for doing dynamic sql in a cursor. This has a lot of red flags all over it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the code would look like this:

```
DECLARE @NextVal BIGINT;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql,
                      N'@NextVal BIGINT OUTPUT',
                      @NextVal=@NextVal OUTPUT ;
```

You need a place to put the output value.

Comment: I already declared the variable but it still gives me the error??? I am using the variable inside the cursor.